# Create REG_NONE registry value in Inno Setup

Tags: windows, registry, inno-setup

I am experimenting with creating Setup exe files.
I use Inno Setup and I found a problem.
When I create a `REG_NONE` entry, it gets ignored while installing the program.

```
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\{#MyAppAssocExtmidi}\OpenWithProgIds"; \
  ValueType: none; ValueName: "WMP11.AssocFile.MIDI" ; ValueData: ""; \
  Flags: uninsdeletevalue
```

[image: Registryentry]

I just want to create a `REG_NONE` entry with the `ValueDATA` of `00000000` (binary zero). I need it for `.midi` files to work. The problem I have when I compile the setup exe and then install it, there is no `REG_NONE` created. It does create all other like `BINARY` or `SZ` but not the `NONE` entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inno Setup cannot create `REG_NONE` registry values. The purpose of the [`none` keyword](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection&anchor=ValueType) is different.

You would have to resort to creating the key using an external tool, for example using the [`reg` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg):

```
[Run]
Filename: reg; Parameters: "add ""Software\Classes\{#MyAppAssocExtmidi}\OpenWithProgIds"" /v WMP11.AssocFile.MIDI /t REG_NONE"
```

And similarly for uninstall using `[UninstallRun]`.

Answer (score 1):

The excepted answer is correct. I'd like to add that it is not necessary to use `REG_NONE`. To register a default application for a file extension by key `OpenWithProgIds` it is also fine to use type `binary` and to omit the `ValueData`. Also I'm adding the flag `uninsdeletkeyifempty` here.

```
Root: HKA; Subkey: "Software\Classes\{#MyAppAssocExtmidi}\OpenWithProgIds"; \
  ValueType: binary; ValueName: "WMP11.AssocFile.MIDI" ; \
  Flags: uninsdeletevalue uninsdeletekeyifempty
```

Tested with Win 10 1809.